Is the derived support $\{x\in X\:|\: \mathsf{L}x^* M\neq 0\}$ closed?
Let $X$ be a scheme and consider an object $M$ of its derived category $\mathsf{D}_\text{qc}(X)$, defined as the full subcategory of $\mathsf{D}(\textsf{Mod}(\mathcal{O}_X))$ consisting of the complexes with quasi-coherent cohomology.
I'm interested in the set $\operatorname{supp}M:=\{x\in X\:|\: M\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}^\mathsf{L} \kappa(x)\neq 0\}$. If $X$ is noetherian and $M$ lies in the subcategory $\mathsf{D}^b_\text{coh}(X)$, then $\operatorname{supp}M$ coincides with the usual support $\operatorname{Supp}M$ and it's a closed subset of $X$.
In general, $\operatorname{supp}M$ may not be a closed subset of $X$. This leads to the question: if $X_0$ is the set of closed points of $X$, is it always true that $\operatorname{supp}M\cap X_0$ is closed in $X_0$?

What if $M$ is the pushforward of the structure sheaf of an open subscheme?

Let $A$ be any subset of $X_0$, and consider the direct sum of the skyscraper sheaves at each point of $A$.

No, in fact any subset of $X_0$ can be the support of a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$. Indeed, suppose $A \subseteq X_0$ and consider the direct sum of skyscraper sheaves
$$M= \bigoplus_{x\in A} \kappa(x).$$
Then I claim that $Supp(M)=A$.
To see this, note that the functor $(-) \otimes_{\mathcal O_X}^L \kappa(x)$ commutes with direct sums, and $H^0 (\kappa(x) \otimes^L_{\mathcal O_X} \kappa(x)) = \kappa(x) \neq 0$.)
